# Denoting the whole in Position/Extract/ReplacePart

Tags: replacement, argument-patterns, expression-manipulation

`Position` returns lists of numbers consumed by `Extract`, `ReplacePart` and others as "positions" in arbitrarily complex forms. This works great:
`Position[x+f[x],x]` --> `{{1}, {2, 1}}`, 2 matches, each of which can be fed to `Extract[x+f[x],{1}]` --> `x` and to `ReplacePart[x+f[x],{2,1}->y]` -->`x+f[y]`.

However, there seems to be a hiccup when matching the **whole** input expression. `Position[x+f[x],x+f[x]]` --> `{{}}`. This is documented behavior: "*A part specification {} returned by Position represents the whole of expr.*"

But... `Extract[x+f[x],{}]` --> `{}`, which seems clearly wrong (there isn't an empty list anywhere in `x+f[x]`). Interestingly, `Extract[x + f[x], {{}}]` --> `{x + f[x]}` works; this is the "extract a list of positions" syntax. But this breaks the easy connection between `Position` and `Extract` without using an awkward "ask for a list of one then take the first answer" work-around.

Even worse, `ReplacePart[x + f[x], {} -> y]` --> `x + f[x]`, i.e. no replacement, while `ReplacePart[x + f[x], {{}} -> y]` --> `y` -- `ReplacePart` seems to want a special `{{}}` form for the whole. (Note that this isn't ReplacePart's multiple-value syntax, which also doesn't work: `ReplacePart[x + f[x], {{} -> y}]` --> `x + f[x]`, and so there's no easy work-around to make this work here.

So... what's going on here? Both `Extract` and `ReplaceParts` are documented to use `Position`'s output, but neither does when it comes to the whole. Is there a principled approach to take? (Right now, I'm just special-casing this, but that seems utterly unsatisfying...)

Thanks
-- perry

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Position returns lists of numbers consumed by Extract, ReplacePart and
> others as "positions" in arbitrarily complex forms.

True

> This works great
> Position[x+f[x],x] --> {{1}, {2, 1}}, 2 matches, each of which can be
> fed to Extract[x+f[x],{1}] --> x and to ReplacePart[x+f[x],{2,1}->y]
> -->x+f[y].

Yes, it works great. `Extract` and `Position` are fully compatible, but you don't use `Extract` in this compatible way. The compatibility is effective when you insert the **whole** result of `Position` in `Extract` (as opposed of taking each element of the result in turn):

```
Extract[x + f[x], Position[x + f[x], x]]
```

> {x, x}

What you call the "work-around" later is the normal use of `Extract`. By "normal" I mean the more general one, the one that resists corner cases (in particular the case "get the whole initial expression"). The use of contructions like `Extract[x + f[x], 2]` is a shorthand for `First[Extract[x + f[x], {{2}}]]`, a form that is too long and too complicated for such a simple action.

So for extracting the whole expression, use this :

```
positions = Position[x + f[x], x + f[x]]
First[Extract[x + f[x], positions]]
```

> x + f[x]

In the same manner, in your example `Extract[x + f[x], {}]`, {} should be interpreted as the list of the elements to extract, ie nothing. It is the "normal" interpetation of `Extract` I mention above (as opposed to the shorthand interpetation).

Comment: Extract[h[a, b], {}] and Extract[h[a, b], {{}}] are documented in the documentation of Extract (/Possibles Issues)

Comment: Maybe I should replace the word "normal" by something else ("generalised"?)

Comment: Andre, I need to pick the list-of-matches returned by Position apart and process each match individually (by mapping over it), and each individual process needs to extract "its" value. Your suggested Extract[expr, Position[expr, pattern]] syntax always returns all matched values, discarding the position I need for processing, so it's insufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Ah. More reading. So both Extract and ReplacePart have an "Issues" entry explaining that {{}} denotes the whole. It looks like my confusion is actually with `Position`: `Position[2 x,_]` --> `{{0}, {1}, {2}, {}}`. This is a **list** of matches, one of which is `{}`, as documented under `Position`: a single empty list. Yet Extract/ReplacePart expect a nested list to denote the whole. So how are they (naturally) compatible?

Comment: Yes, Position returns a list of matches. If you want to extract the expression corresponding to the lastest match (the whole original expression), do something like that : `exp = 2 x; positions = Position[exp, _]; First[Extract[exp, {positions[[4]]}]]`. There are many ways to do that, but nothing shortert than adding a level of {} and remove it at end. You may find this not natural, but it"s the only way to be compatible with the corner cases.

Comment: Andre, thank you. I think I have a full story now. In particular, for `ReplacePart` a similar strategy seems to work: `ReplacePart[x+f[x], {{2,1}}->y]` --> `x+f[y]` (a list-of-one positions). Weird but manageable.